# How to select random number of elements from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, random

Assume that I have a list

```
a = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

and I want to have a function that outputs a subset of the list such that with probability p=0.2 each element will be selected i.e. we toss a coin (that is not fair because p=0.2) when going trough the list and if it's heads we will take that element to the new list. At this moment I have implemented this as

```
z={};
Do[If[RandomChoice[{0.2, 1 - 0.2} -> {True, False}], 
AppendTo[z, a[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[a]}]
```

which seems a bit stupid way of doing it. Also I couldn't find a command in the documentation that does this.

Comment: `a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
rv = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[.2], Length@a];
Pick[a, rv, 1]`?

Comment: Or `Pick[
 a,
 RandomChoice[{0.8, 0.2} -> {0, 1}, Length[a]],
 1
 ]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[123]
Pick[a, RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[.2], Length@a], 1]
```

> {2, 3, 4}

Alternatively,

```
Flatten[RandomChoice[{.2, .8} -> {#, {}}] & /@ a]
```

> {1, 5}

Comment: Also: `Reap[Scan[If[RandomChoice[{.2, 1 - .2} -> {True, False}], Sow[#]] &, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]]`